# Issue with selenium chrome driver saying I have the wrong permission

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

This is my code

```
def driver():
length_of_string = 5
random_string = "".join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters) for i in range(length_of_string))
driver = webdriver.Chrome() # Ex. Mine is "C:\Users\Tevin\Downloads\chromedriver"
```

For some reason, calling the driver doesn't work. I've tried everything.

- I put in the executable path directly and that also had the same error.
- I installed the correct version of chromedriver
- I also have the chromedriver in my env variables

This is the error I get

````
  warnings.warn("urllib3 ({}) or chardet ({}) doesn't match a supported "
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vincentqchen/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 74, in start
    self.process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, env=self.env,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__       
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,       
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1702, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)       
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'chromedriver'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:    

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cbbot.py", line 29, in <module>
    driver()
  File "cbbot.py", line 9, in driver
    driver = webdriver.Chrome() # Ex. Mine is "C:\Users\Tevin\Downloads\chromedriver"
  File "/home/vincentqchen/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 69, in __init__
    super(WebDriver, self).__init__(DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['browserName'], "goog",
  File "/home/vincentqchen/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 90, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/home/vincentqchen/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 89, in start
    raise WebDriverException(
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable may have wrong permissions. Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/home```
````

Comment: on Linux it would need to set it executable `chmod a+x /path/to/chromedriver`. You should check directly in console/terminal if you can run `chromedriver`

Comment: how do you put path directly in code? Maybe you used wrong path. You chould check if you can access it with `os.path.exists(your_path)`